# Writing data into MongoDB with Crunch

Tags: mongodb, apache-crunch, bigdata

We're going to use Apache Crunch to implement our new solutions. We'd like to extract data from HBase and then apply some logic in order to filter out unqualifying ones and at last write the data in a structured way into MongoDB for further processing. Is this feasible? Any ideas about how to make Crunch work with MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

Mongo has a Java driver. So, if you need to do any mongo operation, you can call the driver to get Mongo connection and insert the records. The details of how to use Java to connect to Mongo is covered [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/#getting-started-with-java-driver). Since you are writing a Java code, you should be able to use this driver to do your operation. I am assuming you are using Java.